# R: Error in parLapply - $ invalid for atomic vectors only occurs running in parallel

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I tried to look for a duplicate question and I know many people have asked about parLapply in R so I apologize if I missed one that is applicable to my situation.

Problem: I have the following function that runs correctly in R but when I try to run it in parallel using parLapply (I'm on a windows machine) I get the error that `$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`. The error mentions that 3 nodes produced the errors no matter how many nodes I set my cluster at, for example I have 8 cores on my desktop so I set the cluster to 7 nodes.
Here is example code showing where the problem is:

```
library(parallel)
library(doParallel)
library(arrangements)

#Function

 perms <- function(inputs)
  {
    x <- 0
    L <- 2^length(inputs$w)
     ip <- inputs$ip
    for( i in 1:L)
    {
      y <- ip$getnext()%*%inputs$w
      if (inputs$t >= y)
      {
        x <- x + 1
      }
    }
    return(x)
  }

#Inputs is a list of several other variables that are created before this 
#function runs (w, t_obs and iperm), here is a reproducible example of them
#W is derived from my data, this is just an easy way to make a reproducible example


  set.seed(1)
  m <- 15
  W <- matrix(runif(15,0,1))
  iperm <- arrangements::ipermutations(0:1, m, replace = T)
  t_obs <- 5

  inputs <- list(W,t_obs, iperm)
  names(inputs) <- c("w", "t", "ip")

#If I run the function not in parallel
perms(inputs)

#It gives a value of 27322 for this example data
```

This runs exactly as it should, however when I try the following to run in parallel I get an error

```
#make the cluster
  cor <- detectCores()
  cl<-makeCluster(cor-1,type="SOCK")

#passing library and arguments
  clusterExport(cl, c("inputs"))
  clusterEvalQ(cl, {
    library(arrangements)
  })

  results <- parLapply(cl, inputs, perms)
```

I get the error:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  3 nodes produced errors; first error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

However I've checked to see if anything is an atomic vector using `is.atomic()`, and using `is.recursive(inputs)` it says this is `TRUE`.

My question is why am I getting this error when I try to run this using `parLapply` when the function otherwise runs correctly and is there a reason is says "3 nodes produced errors" even when I have 7 nodes?

Comment: Perhaps a typo, but you never define `m` used in `ipermutations`.

Comment: @r2evans yes a typo, m is defined as 15 elsewhere in the code, I've added that. I don't think I would need to pass that in clusterExport since only iperm depends on it and I pass iperm because it is a part of inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says "3 nodes" because, as you're passing it to `parLapply`, you are only activating three nodes. The first argument to `parLapply` should be a `list` of things, each element to pass to each node. In your case, your `inputs` is a list, correct, but it is being broken down, such that your three nodes are effectively seeing:

```r
# node 1
perms(inputs[[1]]) # effectively inputs$w
# node 2
perms(inputs[[2]]) # effectively inputs$t
# node 3
perms(inputs[[3]]) # effectively inputs$ip
# nodes 4-7 idle
```

You could replicate this on the local host (not `parallel`) with:

```r
lapply(inputs, perms)
```

and when you see it like that, perhaps it becomes a little more obvious what is being passed to your nodes. (If you want to see if further, do `debug(perms)` then run the `lapply` above, and see what the `inputs` inside that function call looks like.)

To get this to work once on one node (I think not what you're trying to do), you could do

```r
parLapply(cl, list(inputs), perms)
```

But that's only going to run one instance on one node. Perhaps you would prefer to do something like:

```r
parLapply(cl, replicate(7, inputs, simplify=FALSE), perms)
```

Comment: That's helpful for understanding what is going on. I didn't think the list would be broken up like that. This runs however it returns 27322 for each node; I was hoping to split the work up among the nodes instead of having them all do the same thing since as m gets large iperm (number of permutations gets huge). To do this I suppose I need to break iperm part of inputs into chunks that are approximately (number of permutations /number of nodes)? I think I should be able to do this with iperm$getnext(number of perms/number of nodes).

Comment: Is `arrangements::ipermutation` stochastic? I'm not familiar, sorry ... regardless, if you want different results, you likely need to calculate the randomness either (a) before parallel, `n` times; or (b) within the nodes. I recommend the former, as the latter introduces some challenges in reproducibility (random seed management).

Comment: The part that I "know" is random is `W`, and you only generate that once. Perhaps something like `input_list <- replicate(7, { W <- matrix(runif(...)); list(w=W, t=t_obs, ip=iperm); }, simplify=FALSE)`, then `parLapply(cl, input_list, perms)`. The more I think about it, I wonder how `iperm` is working on the nodes, since as an object I had assumed that its persistence was effected with an `environment`, which is notably not compatible with nodes on a cluster ...

Comment: (My *guess* on why the [`iperm` instance of an `R6` object](https://github.com/randy3k/arrangements/blob/master/R/permutations.R#L190) -- which [is an environment](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/R6/versions/2.4.0/topics/R6Class) -- still works is that perhaps it regenerates its environment on each node?? That seems magical to me, not intuitive. It might be necessary to generate `iperm` on each node, should be trivial enough.)

Comment: I don't think arrangements::ipermutations is stochastic, it's list of all combinations. W actually isn't random, that was just an easy way to make a reproducible example, the actual values of W are defined from my data (ill edit for clarity. It's persistence is a little beyond my R understanding. I'm currently just trying to break up iperm into different chunks and pass them to the nodes. For example with m <- 5, there are 2^15 = 32768 combinations, I can break these up into chunks using `chunk <- floor((2^m)/(cor-1))` and then just create a list with everything I need for the different nodes.

Comment: Ok, so your call to `arrangements::ipermutation` could eventually be responsible for 32k results ... got it. If you can create a distinct `iperm` generator for each node, then you'd want to form your `inputs_list <- Map(list, t=list(t_obs), w=list(W), ip=list_len7_of_iperms)`, which will give you a list where all `t`s and `w`s are constant between them, but the `ip`s will be different.

Comment: I've got a little ways to go to get exactly what I'm looking for but you've certainly answered the original question. Very helpful. When I'm able to figure out exactly how to pass different permutations to different nodes I'll post that as an answer just for anyone who might do something similar.

Comment: I'd suggest to make a bold comment on `debug(perms)`. This saved my day. Although I knew the command, you made me aware to use it in this context - and it even works in parallel mode!!!

Comment: Interesting that it worked in parallel, but on thinking about it, I think I know why: it caused the local R (*this* node, not any other node) to debug-ify that function, so it works. If you insert a `browser()` in the function and then export it to the cluster, it won't work (all other nodes will fail) because they have no user-interactivity. Glad it helped, Christoph!

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding an answer in case anyone with a similar problem comes across this. @r2evans answered my original question which lead to a realization that even fixing the above problems would not get me the desired result (see comments to his answer).

Problem: Using the package arrangements to generate a large number of combinations and apply a function to the combinations. This becomes very time consuming as the number of combinations gets huge. What we need to do is split the combinations into chunks depending on the number of cores you will using to run in parallel and then do the calculations in each node only on that specific chunk of the combinations.

Solution:

```
cor <- detectCores()-1
cl<-makeCluster(cor,type="SOCK")

set.seed(1)
m <- 15
W <- matrix(runif(15,0,1))
#iperm <- arrangements::ipermutations(0:1, m, replace = T)
t_obs <- 5
chunk_list <- list()
for (i in 1:cor)
{
  chunk_list[i] <- i

}
chunk_size <- floor((2^m)/(cor))
chunk_size <- c(rep(chunk_size,cor-1), (2^m)-chunk_size*(cor-1))

inputs_list <- Map(list, t=list(t_obs), w=list(W), chunk_list = chunk_list, chunk_size = list(chunk_size))

#inputs <- list(W,t_obs, iperm)
#names(inputs) <- c("w", "t", "ip", "chunk_it")




perms <- function(inputs)
{
  x <- 0
  L <- 2^length(inputs$w)
  ip <- arrangements::ipermutations(0:1, m, replace = T)

  chunk_size <- floor((2^m)/(cor))
  chunk_size <- c(rep(chunk_size,cor-1), (2^m)-chunk_size*(cor-1))

 if (inputs$chunk_list !=1)
  {
    ip$getnext(sum(chunk_size[1:inputs$chunk_list-1]))

  }


  for( i in 1:chunk_size[inputs$chunk_list])
  {
    y <- ip$getnext()%*%inputs$w
    if (inputs$t >= y)
    {
      x <- x + 1
    }

  }
  return(x)
}




clusterExport(cl, c("inputs_list", "m", "cor"))
clusterEvalQ(cl, {
  library(arrangements)
})

system.time(results <- parLapply(cl, inputs_list, perms))
Reduce(`+`, results)
```

What I did was split the total number of combinations up into different chunks, i.e. the first 4681 (I have 7 nodes assigned to cor), the second and so on and made sure I didn't miss any combinations. Then I changed my original function to generate the permutations in each node but to basically skip to the combination it should start calculating on, so for node 1 it starts with the first combination but for node it it starts with the 4682 and so on. I'm still working on optimizing this because it's currently only about 4 times as fast as running it in parallel even though I'm using 7 cores. I think the skip in the permutation option will speed this up but I haven't checked yet. Hopefully this is helpful to someone else, it speeds up my estimated time to run (with m = 25, not 15) a simulation from about 10 days to about 2.5 days.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass dplyr to the nodes to solve this

```
clusterEvalQ(clust,{library (dplyr)})
```

The above code should solve your issue.